# Constrained Circular Mean Optimization

Tags: algorithm

### Problem Statement

Given samples `S = { (x1, f(x2)), (x2, f(x2)), ... (xn, f(xn)) }` of a function `f(x)` on a circular domain `x ∈ [0, 1)`, i.e. the argument `x=1` is equivalent to `x=0`. `S` can be assumed to be sorted with respect to the x-values. `n` can be assumed to be less than 100.

I want to pick a subset of these samples `E = (e1, e2, ... ek) ⊂ S` with the following constraints. Assuming that `E` is ordered with respect to the x-values:

```
minDist <= e(i + 1).x - e(i).x <= maxDist   for all i ∈ (1, k - 1)
minDist <=   e1.x + 1 - ek.x   <= maxDist
```

I.e. two neighboring selected samples must be farther than `minDist` but no more than `maxDist` away from each other. There will always be a subset `E` that fulfills these constraints.

But I don't want to pick any subset. I want an optimal one:

```
arg min 1/k  *   ∑   e.f
 E, k          e ∈ E
```

I.e. the number of selected samples is not defined. And I want to pick samples, such that their mean is minimized.

### Observations

Clearly, `k` is bounded by `minDist` and `maxDist`:

```
1 / maxDist <= k <= 1 / minDist
```

In many cases, the problem seems to be reducable to the local minima of `S`. However, if there is no subset of the local minima that does fulfill the constraints, this is not possible.

### Possible Solutions

A greedy algorithm could visit samples in the order of `f(x)` (from minimum to maximum). It would then insert the sample into `E` if it does not violate the lower bound constraint. However, this does not necessarily lead to a valid solution. Especially not an optimal one. Other greedy approaches are imaginable. E.g. picking minimal samples in regions where the constraint is not yet fulfilled.

Brute-forcing all possible solutions is obviously too slow. Graph-based algorithms on the graph of solutions may speed this up but the graphs are most likely exponentially large.

### Question

Has anyone an idea for a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, assume a first point in a sequence of samples - so you will end up trying this with the first point e.g. all points within maxdist past 0.

Now run a dynamic program from that point, where at each point the state is (number of samples accepted so far) and you consider all sequences that end by selecting that point and have that number of samples accepted and store the smallest sum produced by any such sequence for each possible state. You can work out the answers at any point by looking back to the best answers for previous points.

Once you get to the end, work out the averages for all of the answers that have got to within maxdist of wrapping around and pick the best.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The subproblems are parametrized by the number of selections, so that minimizing sum is equivalent to minimizing mean.

Comment: An example subproblem is "what is the best sum for a stretch of 13 points from point 0 terminating in point 53, which is chosen as the last point chosen".

Comment: Ok, I see that min mean can be solved by solving min sum for all possible `k`. But I am not convinced that min sum is a DP problem, given the quite unhandy constraints. I.e. I don't see how the entire problem breaks down into sub problems.

Comment: In solving my example sub-problem you know the final point is point 53 and you will have 13 points, so look for answers for 12-point problems where the last point quoted for that problem is within a legal distance of point 53 and choose whatever gives you the best answer for the 13-point problem ending at point 53. You are satisfying the first constraint at each sub-problem and you can check the second constraint when you pick the completed sequences to average because you have assumed the position of the first point.

Comment: Ok, great. I implemented it and it seems to work fine. The time complexity (assuming a widely uniform distribution of the samples) seems to be `O(maxDist^2 / minDist * n^3)`.